# C# api : MCV files are corrupted when download from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, download

I'm trying to create a simple upload/download platform. Basically, I upload file from a browser that sends them onto an Azure Blob storage, then I try to download them from the same browser, but if the upload works fine, the download gives corrupted files.

I'm using .net core 2.2 to fetch the file from Azure's Blob storage and send them back to the client side. I tried downloading them directly from Azure or write them locally with c# and it works fine. Only when I try to download them client-side are they corrupted.

I also tried uploading plain text files and after downloading them they're fine. If I try to use text files with special characters, however, said special character come out wrong. E.G : if I upload a file whose content is "àé&"ç&éàéç&! it will result in a file whose content is "��&"�&����&!

C# CODE :

```cs
[Route("download/{fileId}")]
[HttpGet()]
  public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadAsync(Guid fileId){
  var file = ClientPortalDbContext.Files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == fileId);
  if (file == null) return null;

  // get Blob on Blob storage
  var stream = new IO.MemoryStream();
  var container = CloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
  bool created = await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

  if (created) return;

  var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
  if (blob.Exists())
  {
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(target);
    target.Position = 0;
  }
  #if DEBUG
  var reader = new IO.BinaryReader(stream);
  var bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
  await 

 IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "filedump.bin"), bytes);
  stream.Position = 0;
  #endif
  var file = File(stream, "application/octet");
  return file;        
}
```

JS CODE

```
downloadFile = async (fileId:string) => { 
        const userData: Msal.AuthResponse = await handleNewCall()
        return Axios.get(`MYAPI/api/files/download/${fileId}`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'responseType': "arraybuffer",
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (userData.accessToken)
            },
        })
    },

function str2bytes (str:string) {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
       bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
     }
     return bytes;
 }

downloadFile(props.accessors,onDownloadProgress).then((response: any) => {
      const blob: Blob = new Blob([str2bytes(response.data)],{type:'application/octet-stream'});
      var url: string = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const anchor: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a");
      anchor.href = url;
      anchor.download = props.title;
      anchor.click();
}
```

Additionally, the file are almost twice the size of what they're supposed to be. I tried to put all the reponse text in the blob without converting it to UInt8array but it doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Ive run into this before and it always had to do with the response types. Check the response type of your api call and make sure it matches what you are putting here:
const blob: Blob = new Blob([str2bytes(response.data)],{type:'application/octet-stream'});

most browsers will corrupt a file if, for example you try to save an html document as a pdf. The file type that is saved must match the headers that come back from the server. My application is doing this when making api call: { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'll try that.